# Multiple websockets java

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

[deprecated]
ok I'm opening a connection to a specific port, and keeping it open therefore I cannot open a second connection to the same port.

Seeing that it took me too long to find the answer, I'm going to leave this question.

I would like to know if I can have more than one instance of a websocket running in the same webpage.
I'm building an application just for learning , and I would like to display in the same page the notifications and a separated notification box.

I'm creating the websocket in java ,i m using the struts 2 framework, and javascript for handling the client side.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var wsPath = "<s:url value='/websocket' />" + isComment + id;
        var wsUri = "ws://" + window.location.host + wsPath;
        var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

I'm going to try creating a secondary "set" of functions and a new instance of the same websocket class to have something like this:

```
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) }; 
websocketnotifications.onopen = function(evt) { onOpenNotifications(evt) };
```

I would like to know if this is the normal way to do it or if there is a better way. Because I'm not finding any other solution, and I would like to implement it in the right way.

Comment: No you Cant have multiple websocket in a single page.

Comment: are you using the FullFeatured Broker?  or can you post your configuration ?

Comment: `ok i m openning a connection to a specific port, and keeping it open therefor i can not open a second connection to the same port` is this in the same page also ?   why dont use the current websocket ?

Comment: i think i m goig to do it parsing information from the  same websocket, like you are saying. thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?  having multiple function to listen from the server?

**Sample Snippet**

```
   var contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";

    var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:9991/BlackJackServer/ws");

    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    var connectCallback = function() {
          // This how I populate multiple functions when server send a message to this topics
          stompClient.subscribe('/topic/lobby', renderLobby);
          stompClient.subscribe('/topic/${player.username}/updatePlayerStatus', renderPlayerStatus);
          stompClient.subscribe('/topic/${player.username}/renderPlayerChips', renderPlayerChips);
    };

    var errorCallback = function(error) {
          alert("Server Maintenance");
    };

    stompClient.connect({}, connectCallback, errorCallback);

    //Close the WebSocket When Refreshing or Reloading the Page.    
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        // disable onclose handler first
        socket.onclose = function () {}; 
        socket.close();
    };

    function renderPlayerStatus(response){
        var status = response.body;
        if(status == '"ONLINE"'){
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    function renderPlayerChips(response){
       var updatedPlayerChips = response.body;
       $('#chips').empty();
       $('#chips').append("Chips : "+updatedPlayerChips);
    }
```